# smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

Tags: python, email, smtp

\I'm getting an authentication error. I'm 100% certain my email and password are correct (types them in). I've attached a picture of my office.outlook.com settings for IMAP and POP[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpz4y.png)

```
import smtplib

# initialize connection to our email server, we will use Outlook here
smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', port='587')

smtp.ehlo()  # send the extended hello to our server
smtp.starttls()  # tell server we want to communicate with TLS encryption

smtp.login('support@name.com', 'emailpassword')  # login to our email server

# send our email message 'msg' to our boss
smtp.sendmail('support@name.com',
              'support@name.com',
              msg.as_string())
              
smtp.quit()  # finally, don't forget to close the connection
```

Comment: What is the rest of the error? Could you incorporate it into your message instead of the title?